# stop google.com from redirecting to local web page

Tags: firefox, redirection, google-search, google-toolbar

When I type `http://google.com` into the locaton bar and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> the URL bar redirects to:

> file:///C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/Google_Toolbar/Google_Toolbar/1.0.0.0/MyGoogle.html

When this happens I can still search google but the URL bar continues to show the local address. This only occurs in both Firefox and Chrome but only for `google.com` and not other sites.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Try disabling Google Toolbar

Answer (score 5):

Your **Google Toolbar** plugin is causing this behavior. Try disabling it.